# (MySQL / MariaDB) Create Triggers for all Table-Changes

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-trigger

I wan't to create `Triggers` to synchronize a Node.js Application with the database.

How i can create a global trigger, that watch over all available tables? An `*` as placeholder won't work here.

The second question is, which global variables available... I wan't to store in the `changes`-Table the informations, which changes affected like:

```
id      table     row      value_new      value_old          time_created
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       users     email    test@test.de   test@example.com    2018-04-29 14:48:23
```

Here you see, the Table `users` had changed on row `email` with the listened values...

How i can get the values for `table` and `row`, for sample?

To synchronize the data, i wan't to use the application start/crawl time. On startup, user data will be fetched, but all other data with a newer timestamp will be updated after the application was started.

Comment: "How i can create a global trigger, that watch over all available tables?" There isn't annything like a global trigger.. You need to create the triggers separated on every table.

Comment: I might be wrong of course, but to the best of my recollection there is no DBMS in which you can define a GLOBAL trigger for all tables. This capability, by the way, does not make sense at all in my opinion. Imagine that such thing would exist, the trigger would need to know the structure of each and every table to be able to do something, or (even worse) find out the structure of the currently updated table and act accordingly. To a heavy process for a trigger.

Comment: Agree with the other comments - nothing like that exists. If it did, you would end up with a race condition if your trigger inserted or updated a table. BTW, by "row" do you mean column?

Comment: Okay, i think to create triggers for each table is lots of complex by spending times... I think another solution is to create an versioning-like system. For sample: each table has an `version` field, which will be count up on a change/update. If a newer "version" is available (a cronjob check it on specific interval), the new data will be fetched...